# UIButton Autolayout size setting

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios-autolayout

I have a UIButton control placed in the view, there is a large background image set in the button, let's say the size of image is 600 x 300, and the size of button is 100 X 40, now I want to add the constraints to limit the width of button >= 100 and <= 200 depends on the title width.

The problem is that the button width always stretch to 200 instead of the actual title width, because the background image is too large than 200 pixel. But what I want is to make the width fit with title other than the background image.

I have tried to reduce the priority of the button imageview in horizontal using setContentHuggingPriority and setContentCompressionResistancePriority, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an IBOutlet for a width constraint for your button then you can say something like:

```
self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant = button.titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(button.frame.size).width
```

Or if you need it in objective-c:

```
self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant = [self.button.titleLabel sizeThatFits:self.button.frame.size].width;
```

Comment: what is .buttonWidthConstraint.constant? I don't find any property like that. Or do you mean adding a width constraint to the button? I did that, I added a >= 100 and <=200 width constraint to the button already as I described.

Comment: "You should create an IBOutlet" for the width constraint you added. By way of example, I called it "buttonWidthConstraint." You can create an IBOutlet by control dragging from the view hierarchy to your class.

Comment: I got what you mean. Well, although I don't want to have part of storyboard part of code, this is the best solution so far. Thanks. By the way,  sizeThatFits(button.frame.size) won't do the job. It should be title.boundingRectWithSize(...).width + button.titleLabel.frame.origin.x + title inset left and right. Please change it and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't do the job?"

Comment: It does not change the width properly, because button.frame.size is affected by the background image rather than title, so button.frame.size.width = 200 in my case, and sizeThatFits just set title label width to the button width. Which is not the thing I want.

Comment: Are you calling sizeThatFits on the button or on the button's titleLabel, as I do in the code provided? It works perfectly fine for me in the sample project I created. It will size the button's width to exact the width of the titleLabel. You can add a buffer to the constraint if you want some padding. Moreover, I am almost 100% certain that sizeThatFit simply calls boundingRectWithSize, so that is not a better solution. BTW, you should delete the width constraints that are >= 100 and <= 200 if you haven't already, maybe that's why you are getting bizarre results.

Comment: It is not the constraint problem. button.titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(button.frame.size) always return a smaller size. It seems sizeThatFits does not count the changed font. the label font is system font size 20, the width calculated by boundingRectWithSize is 135, while  sizeThatFits always return 63. (I did checked the font has been changed)

Comment: I can change the font and it still sizes perfectly. I can change it in IB or in code with the same result. As I said sizeThatFits calls boundingRectWithSize but passes the attributes from the titleLabel, hence is an easy more elegant solution.

Comment: I figure out the problem. your are right, sizeThatFits does work normally UNLESS title is changed. When the button title is changed by setTitle(title, forState: .Normal), the button.titlelable.text is not changed immediately. which means sizeThatFits only calculate the button.titlelable.text width, not the button state title. And this cause the wrong width.